# Set header key based on SSL ID

Tags: ssl, haproxy

Is there a way to set a header key based on SSL ID value with HAProxy 1.5? We would like to use the SSL ID as the session ID for clients who do not support cookies.

Comment: See [docwiki.cisco.com](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer_Persistence_Configuration_Example) for limitation on SSL ID's

Comment: I assume you are using SSL offloading on the HAproxy?

Answer (score 1):

First, to my knowledge, the answer is no.

However, there are other handy techniques to handle folks who do not support cookies.  Provided that Javascript is supported, take a page out of Microsoft's book and try something that's actually pretty cool about ASP.NET apps.

Add a Javascript on_click handler to every link and an on_submit to forms.  Then simply generate a post that contains the session ID, which is hidden in a hidden field or embedded in the Javascript.  Works quite well and removes the requirement for cookies.

For more information see here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

To be clear, I'm not suggesting that you use ASP.NET.  I'm just suggesting that you use the technique.  :)